# Object Recognition Using Hog Features

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

Hi I'm going to recognize objects on my images

Before creating a dataset to train with **svm** I just cropped single part of my image computed hog descriptors put them into svmdetector and then tried to find it using multiscale detection on my original image.

however detection points out center of my image. I am not sure if I'm doing something wrong with hog detection or I just mark wrong place.

this is my image

[image]

this is cropped part of it

[image]

and this is the result

[image]

and my code is below.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
Mat img2 = imread("part.jpg");
Mat img3 = imread("full.jpg");
    HOGDescriptor d2( Size(img2.rows,img2.cols), Size(8,8), Size(4,4), Size(4,4), 9);
    HOGDescriptor d3;
    vector< float> descriptorsValues2,descriptorsValues3;
    vector< Point> locations2,locations3;
    d2.compute( img2, descriptorsValues2, Size(0,0), Size(0,0), locations2);
    d2.setSVMDetector(descriptorsValues2);
    vector< Rect> found,found_filtered;
    d2.detectMultiScale(img3, found, 0, Size(0,0), Size(0,0), 1.05, 2);

size_t i, j;
    for (i=0; i<found.size(); i++)
    {
        Rect r = found[i];
        for (j=0; j<found.size(); j++)
            if (j!=i && (r & found[j])==r)
                break;
        if (j==found.size())
            found_filtered.push_back(r);
    }

    for (i=0; i<found_filtered.size(); i++)
    {
        Rect r = found_filtered[i];
        r.x += cvRound(r.width*0.1);
        r.width = cvRound(r.width*0.8);
        r.y += cvRound(r.height*0.06);
        r.height = cvRound(r.height*0.9);
        rectangle(img3, r.tl(), r.br(), cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 2);
    }

    imshow("video capture", img3);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

thank you.

Comment: If you only need to find the location of a cropped sample inside the main image, you can try Template Matching: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html It is a simpler solution for your problem, unless you need to find objects from rotated samples or from different views. Then, a SVM would be better.