# OpenCV HOG+SVM: assertion failed checkDetectorSize()

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, object-detection

I have a problem with openCV in c++ when I try to set my own SVM detector into the method hog::setSVMDetector(Detector) in openCV.

I followed the following procedure [SVM classifier based on HOG features for "object detection" in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769519/svm-classifier-based-on-hog-features-for-object-detection-in-opencv) and I'm stuck at step 3.

I'm using openCV 3.0 and it's currently built in SVM.
This is how I'm training and building my detector:

TRAIN

```
svm = SVM::create();
svm->setType(type);
svm->setKernel(kernel);
svm->setC(C);

if (kernel == SVM::LINEAR) {
    svm->setDegree(1);
} else if (kernel == SVM::POLY) {
    svm->setDegree(3);
}
svm->train(trainingSamples, ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labels);
```

BUILDING DETECTOR

```
vector<float> alpha;
vector<float> svidx;
vector<float> model;

// Getting Support Vectors
Mat svs = svm->getSupportVectors();

double rho = svm->getDecisionFunction(0, alpha, svidx);

    // Computing w in primal form
for (int i = 0; i < svidx.size(); i++) {
    model.push_back(svs.at<float>(i, 0) * alpha.at(i));
    for (int j = 1; j < svs.cols; j++) {
        model.at(i) += svs.at<float>(i, j) * alpha.at(i);
    }
}

//   Adding rho
    model.push_back(rho);
    return model;
```

The error occur when I try to feed the above model to:

```
hog.setDetector(model);
```

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed
>   (checkDetectorSize()) in setSVMDetector, file
>   /home/dario/Desktop/opencv-3.0.0-rc1/modules/objdetect/src/hog.cpp,
>   line 115 terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'cv::Exception'   what(): 
>   /home/dario/Desktop/opencv-3.0.0-rc1/modules/objdetect/src/hog.cpp:115:
>   error: (-215) checkDetectorSize() in function setSVMDetector

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It might be that you different window size and in that case it will different number of values that are fed into `hog.setDetector(model); 
`

Comment: I've got a similar problem.  I'd like to manually set the detector size to something without a 0.5 aspect ratio.  My reasoning is that I want to detect people that aren't always in the perfect stance that they fit into a 0.5 aspect ratio.  Consider the case of a boxer with arms extended in a punch and knees bent.  I guess this isn't possible due to the use of the pretraine person detection classifier.  Any recommendations?  Perhaps I need to manually train an SVM for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by rewriting the above code as

```
    Ptr<SVM> svm;
    HOGDescriptor my_hog;
    ...
    // Load the trained SVM.
    svm = StatModel::load<SVM>( "model.yml" );
    // Set the trained svm to my_hog
    vector< float > hog_detector;
    get_svm_detector( svm, hog_detector );
    my_hog.setSVMDetector( hog_detector );
```

Comment: Hi, What version of opencv do you use ? Does function get_svm_detector is in opencv？